# Question Regarding a Specific Rational Number

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I ask this after trying to solve it myself unsuccessfully.  It's part of a larger question I'm working on, but have separated this out so as to make it as clear and concise as possible.

Trying to solve this:
$$\text{Let }r \in \, (0,1\, ) \text{ and } r \notin \mathbb{Q}$$
$$\text{Let }r’ \in \, (0,1\, ), r’>r, r’ \notin \mathbb{Q}, \text{ and } r’-r \notin \mathbb{Q}$$
$$\text{Let }q \in A = \{ r’-r+p : p \in \, (r,r+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \}$$
Finally, one of the two statements must be true:
$$\text{1) } \exists q’ \in B = \, (r’,r’+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that }\{q'-p : p \in B\} = \{q-p : p \in A\}$$
$$\text{2) } \nexists q’ \in B = \, (r’,r’+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that }\{q'-p : p \in B\} = \{q-p : p \in A\}$$

Which statement is true?

Comment: I suggest you start by picking specific values of $r,r',q...$ etc. that satisfy the above conditions, and try to understand the problem that way, drawing a picture as you go. It is difficult to keep straight in your head what all the different variables are.

Comment: I have:  specific values, pictures, and everything.  I've attempted to assume statement 1 is true so as to try to arrive at a contradiction, but don't.  I've also attempted to assume statement 2 is true so as to try to arrive a contradiction, but don't.  It seems undecidable as far as I can tell.  I don't think it's like defining a flying unicorn and asking whether it exists though.  I think it's a valid question because everything is well defined.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second statement is true.

Let $q'\in B$. Then
$$\inf(\{p-q': p\in B\})-\inf(\{p-q:p\in A\})=(\inf B-q')-(\inf A-q)=(r'-q')-(r'-q)=q-q'\neq 0,
$$
because $q'\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $q\notin\mathbb{Q}$. So, the sets are different as they have different infima.

Edit: The answer to the corrected question is the same, as
$$\sup(\{q'-p:p\in B\})-\sup(\{q-p:p\in A\})=(q'-\inf B)-(q-\inf A)=q'-q.
$$

Comment: You gave me exactly what I was looking for.  This solves the other question I am working on too!  Showing that the difference between the infima, and that the difference must be a real number (in this case an irrational number) is exactly what I was going for.